# win7-64 sp1: Rename folder (including zip file) error popup

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, service-pack

With the install of Windows 7 x64 Service Pack 1 (SP1) I get a windows explorer popup on any folder rename including .zip files.

> Could not find this item

They are referring to the old name. What a bug. If I click "Try Again' the popup goes away, folder is renamed.

Lots of posts on the net about this but no fixes. I tried a registry patch (that I shouldn't have) and it did nothing to fix. This started happening after the install of sp1.

Comment: I had that problem with W7 Beta and early on with RTM, not sure what was causing it either. I would run a chkdsk on the hard drive C partition, back up your data first.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/renaming-folders-causes-item-not-found-error-in/e2cf38c7-9e77-4256-89de-6308df53d5f9?tm=1299219912631)
 post has the answer that fixed it for me. All you have to do is delete a few registry keys and logout and login.

Comment: I did this and it worked - but how did the original poster figured out what reg keys to delete? Guess that's a whole new question right there.